# Google Sheets Apps Script - Find and Copy cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello Good day!

I am new here, so I apologize if I do something wrong. I need help making a google sheet document script.

Basically what I need is when I click the "My tools>copy to location B" in the menu bar, I want to find current sheet's(Sheet1) cell value in location B(K:K)&(L:L). search it in location A(A:A)&(B:B) of all sheets and copy the train route and location A in reversed(notice the tabs in the pictures). Thank you very much in advance.

Best Regards,

Tim

picture1
[image]

picture2
[image]

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question as well. I can't correlate the narration with the images!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will undoubtedly need some testing and debugging

```
function findAndCopyInReverseSomewhat()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<allSheets.length;j++)
    {
      if(allSheets[j].getName()!='Sheet1')
      {
        var sA=allSheets[j].getDataRange().getValues();
        for(var k=1;k<sA.length;k++)
        {
          if(vA[i][10]==sA[k][0] && vA[i][11]==sA[k][1])
          {
            allSheets[j].getRange(k+1, 3, 1, 10).setValues([[vA[i][9],vA[i][8],vA[i][7],vA[i][6],vA[i][5],vA[i][4],vA[i][3],vA[i][2],vA[i][10],vA[i][11]]]);
          }
        }

      }
    }

  }
}
```